# std::unordered_map in CLion on macOS

Tags: macos, clang, clion, unordered-map

How can I see elements in `std::unordered_map` in CLion debugger?

There is some [recipe](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/05/debug-clion/) how to see `std::map` elements, but it does not work with `std::unordered_map`.

I use clang compiler on macOS 10.13.

Comment: Seems it is your problem in the CLion bug tracker:
CPP-10235 LLDB: Pretty print in debugger doesn't work correctly
[https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-10235]