# CLion cannot resolve type std::unordered_map even though it prompted me to include the header and the compilation works

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake, header-files, clion

For some reason my CLion cannot recognize `std::unordered_map` even though it actually suggested me to include the header by `Alt+Enter` when I first wrote out the type definition. After I included the header by `#include <unordered_map>`, the compilation works as well.

I can even Ctrl+Click on the `include` line to find the header file, but I can't click on the line of type definition (which keeps remaining red). I don't understand why the IDE keeps refusing to recognize the type within the code.

Actually, it then suggests me to include `bits/unordered_map.h`. I can find `unodered_map.h` in both `/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/unordered_map` and `/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/unordered_map.h`. I'm not sure what's the difference between these two. Including either or both doesn't solve the problem.

I added `-std=c++11` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in my `CMakeLists.txt` already.

CLion 2018.1, gcc 7.3.1, Arch Linux.

Comment: Ok. So if you do not include the header file, the compiler or the compilation tool doesn't know anything about the template the header declares. Ummm, yeah, so what is your question, again?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ? Maybe you can try to read it again? After including the header CLion keeps saying it doesn't understand the type definition and keeps showing it in red, even though the compilation succeeds, which makes no sense.

Comment: The IDE is not the compiler. Just because the IDE does not recognise the type doesn't mean the comiler won't. Also; don't expect the IDE to always be up to the same level as the *actual* compiler - it often is not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure. I understand that. That doesn't answer my question about using CLion though. The program compiles fine but it's an annoyance when I code.

Answer (score 3):

Bad news: it's CLion [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-12609).

Good news: it was fixed. Please try using CLion 2018.1.1 EAP. The issue should be fixed in it.

Here is the related [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47094712/stdunordered-map-in-clion-on-macos).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CLion but in Eclipse Luna with TDM-GCC as compiler these errors are usually caused because the project isn't built . Also verify that unordered_map is indeed in the /include folder of your project .
You can also include higher std flags like **-std=c++14** .

Hope this helps!